# Optimistic locking with redis using GET and INCR

Tags: python, redis, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

I want to "lock" a block of code optimistically. 
psuedo code is as follows:

```
revision = GET('lock_key') # default as 0
{
<<block of code>>
}
new_revision = INCR('lock_key')
if new_revision != revision + 1:
    raise Exception # now retry or whatever
```

This looks fine to me since both INCR and GET are atomic.
Do you see any problem with this approach?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few problems with this approach. Firstly, it won't scale well above 2 workers since the faster ones will starve the slower. The flow also lacks atomicity, which may or may not be an issue depending the logic you're running, but race conditions are nasty. Lastly, there's a little of the [observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_%28physics%29#Quantum_mechanics) in play here since you're always INCRing key_lock.

A better approach would be to use Redis' [MULTI](http://redis.io/commands/multi), [EXEC](http://redis.io/commands/exec) and [WATCH](http://redis.io/commands/watch). Redis' [transactions topic](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) discusses this pretty neatly and provides the following example based on your psuedo code:

```
WATCH('lock_key')
revision = GET('lock_key') # default as 0
{
    <<block of code>>
}

MULTI()
new_revision = INCR('lock_key')
if EXEC() is None:
  raise Exception # now retry or whatever
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `<<block of code>>` be between `MULTI` and `EXEC`, and shouldn't there be nothing between `WATCH` and `MULTI`?

Comment: No, the OP didn't indicate that there are any Redis operations in the block